# why statement xmlhttp.onreadystatechange cause this program work once only?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, html

i make a simple REST web service consumer using HTML and javascript. here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script language="javascript">
    var xmlhttp;

    function getdetails() {
        var empno = document.getElementById("empno");
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/TestWS1/rest/hello/" + empno.value;

        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //@slaks: i put it here

        xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

               var empname =  document.getElementById("empname");
               var age =  document.getElementById("age");
               if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    //alert(xmlhttp.status);
                  if ( xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                       var det = eval( "(" +  xmlhttp.responseText + ")");
                       if (det.age > 0 ) {
                          empname.value = det.name;
                          age.value = det.age;
                       }
                       else {
                           empname.value = "";
                           age.value ="";
                           alert("Invalid Employee ID");
                       }
                 }
                 else
                       alert("Error ->" + xmlhttp.responseText);
              }
        }
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Call Employee Service </h1>
   <table>
   <tr>
       <td>Enter Employee ID :  </td>
       <td><input type="text" id="empno" size="10"/>  <input type="button" value="Get Details" onclick="getdetails()"/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Enter Name :  </td>
       <td><input type="text" readonly="true" id="empname" size="20"/> </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td>Employee Age : </td>
       <td><input type="text" readonly="true" id="age" size="10"/> </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

that code only show an employee name and age from the REST web service on the HTML textbox when a getDetail button is pressed. the parameter is employee number (empNo).

the main problem is, why this code only works once??

for example, if i put 1 on the empNo textbox and i pressed getDetail button, for the first time only, it will display the name and the age of the employee based on employee number that i was entered before. but for the second or third i press the getDetail button, it not works anymore. i've tried to give some alert to help me for debugging that code but the result is xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() only works once on the first time i pressed the getDetail button.

has anyone know how to solve this problem?? really stuck in here.. thanks a lot for helping me..

FYI: here's my web service code:

```
package com.webservices.TestWS1;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

//@Path("/hello")
@Path("/hello/{empno}")
public class Hello {        
    @GET   // this method process GET request from client
    @Produces("application/json")   // sends JSON
    public String getJson( @PathParam("empno") int empno) {  // empno represents the empno sent from client   
        switch(empno) {
          case 1 :
              return "{'name':'George Koch', 'age':58}";
          case 2:
              return "{'name':'Peter Norton', 'age':50}";
          default:
              return "{'name':'unknown', 'age':-1}";
      } // end of switch
   } // end of
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this between the script tag

```
function getdetails() {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var empno = document.getElementById("empno");
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/TestWS1/rest/hello/" + empno.value;
        xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

               var empname =  document.getElementById("empname");
               var age =  document.getElementById("age");
               if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    //alert(xmlhttp.status);
                  if ( xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                       var det = eval( "(" +  xmlhttp.responseText + ")");
                       if (det.age > 0 ) {
                          empname.value = det.name;
                          age.value = det.age;
                       }
                       else {
                           empname.value = "";
                           age.value ="";
                           alert("Invalid Employee ID");
                       }
                 }
                 else
                       alert("Error ->" + xmlhttp.responseText);
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer petar, but it still not works for me.. that code only can runs once.. any other suggestion??

Comment: the problem is same petar. for example: for the first i put "1" on the empNo textbox and i press getDetail button. it will show name:employeeA and age:35. for the second one, i put "2" on the empNo textbox and i press getDetail button. it will show name:employeeB and age:40. for the third try i do the same things like the previous one >> put "1" on the empNo textbox. this time there's no response from the server. the name and age was still empty for this time. i've tried to give some alert for debugging and it was proved that the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function is not called (3rd i try)

Comment: The problem seems to be on the server part, I testet your code generating responses like {"name":"test","age":30} and it is ok

Comment: umm.. the server is really simple.. you can see my server code above.. please correct me if i wrong and please give me some suggestion.. i've tried to solve this problem about 3 days and it still not solved.. many thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can't re-use `XMLHttpRequest`s.
You need to create a new `XMLHttpRequest` for each request.

Get rid of your `init()` function.

Comment: thanks for your answer slaks, i've tried your suggestion but it still same.. works for the first time only.. any other suggestion??

Comment: i've edited the code.. please give me some suggestion.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bit late this answer, but to whom it may concern ...

One need to to assign the callback function before one send the request.
So it should be likes this

```
     var url = "http://localhost:8080/TestWS1/rest/hello/" + empno.value;
        xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
          ... some code here
          }
        xmlhttp.send(null);
```